# Creating Excel Spreadsheet with Database Table information

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell, excel

My Goal:
I'm wanting an excel document showing basic information for each table. I'd be happy with the same information shown when you Alt+F1 on the table but ideally I want a separate sheet per table.

I have nearly 1500 tables so I don't really want to do this manually. I started looking at this through PowerShell. With a bit of help from the internet I've got this far. But this just creates a single result set. I'm guessing I just need to put it into a loop. As you might be able to see PowerShell isn't my strongest skill but i am slowly picking it up.

Update:
Managed to get it working. Next step I have is to add hyperlinks to the index page and then I'm going to look at adding multiple tables per sheet to show foreign keys etc.

**

- Updated Code

**

```
## Enter Paramerts ##
$ResultsPath = "C:\Temp\"
$FileName = 'S2CDataDictionary.xlsx'
$SQLServer = 'HD08'
$Database = 'PLAZA'

## Begin ##

## Query for list of tables ##

$GetTableList = @'
Select top 10 name as [TableName]
from sys.tables
Where name not like '[_]%'
Order by name
'@;

##     Query for each table ##

$GetTableInfo = @'
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @objname NVARCHAR(776)
SET @objname = 'xxTableNamexx'

DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME,
   @no VARCHAR(35),
   @yes VARCHAR(35),
   @none VARCHAR(35)

SELECT @no = 'no',
   @yes = 'yes',
   @none = 'none'

DECLARE @precscaletypes NVARCHAR(150)

    SELECT @precscaletypes = N'tinyint,smallint,decimal,int,bigint,real,money,float,numeric,smallmoney,date,time,datetime2,datetimeoffset,'

DECLARE @objid INT

SELECT @objid = object_id
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE object_id = object_id(@objname)

SELECT 'Column_name' = name,
   'Type' = type_name(user_type_id),
   'Computed' = CASE 
         WHEN ColumnProperty(object_id, name, 'IsComputed') = 0
                THEN @no
         ELSE @yes
         END,
   'Length' = convert(INT, max_length),
   'Prec' = CASE 
         WHEN charindex(type_name(system_type_id) + ',', @precscaletypes) > 0
                THEN convert(CHAR(5), ColumnProperty(object_id, name, 'precision'))
         ELSE '     '
         END,
   'Scale' = CASE 
         WHEN charindex(type_name(system_type_id) + ',', @precscaletypes) > 0
                THEN convert(CHAR(5), OdbcScale(system_type_id, scale))
         ELSE '     '
         END,
   'Nullable' = CASE 
         WHEN is_nullable = 0
                THEN @no
         ELSE @yes
         END,
   'TrimTrailingBlanks' = CASE ColumnProperty(object_id, name, 'UsesAnsiTrim')
         WHEN 1
                THEN @no
         WHEN 0
                THEN @yes
         ELSE '(n/a)'
         END,
   'FixedLenNullInSource' = CASE 
         WHEN type_name(system_type_id) NOT IN (
                      'varbinary',
                      'varchar',
                      'binary',
                      'char'
                      )
                THEN '(n/a)'
         WHEN is_nullable = 0
                THEN @no
         ELSE @yes
         END,
   'Collation' = collation_name
FROM sys.all_columns
WHERE object_id = @objid
'@


## SQL Connection ##
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
$Database; User ID=PADMIN;Password=a";

## SQL Command ##
$SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SQLCmd.Connection = $SQLConnection
$SQLCmd = $SQLConnection.CreateCommand() 
$SQLCmd.CommandText = $GetTableList

## Create Index Data Set ##
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSetTable = $Dataset.Tables["Table"]

## Export to Excel, create worksheet for index ##
If ([IO.File]::Exists(($ResultsPath + $FileName))) {Rename-Item ($ResultsPath + $FileName) -NewName ($FileName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")) } ##RenameOldTable If Exists
$DataSetTable | Select TableName | Export-Excel -Path ($ResultsPath + $FileName) -WorkSheetname "Contents" -Title "Index" -TitleSize "24" -TableName "ListOfTables" -TableStyle Medium16 -AutoSize ##Create Contents Page

## For each Table: create worksheet and run table query ##
ForEach ($Table IN $DataSetTable | Select TableName) 
{
            $TableName = $Table -replace ("@{TableName=","") -replace ("}","") ##Need to review
            $QueryText = ($GetTableInfo.Replace("xxTableNamexx",$TableName))
            $SQLCmd.CommandText = $QueryText
            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
            $DataSetTable = $Dataset.Tables["Table"]
            $DataSetTable | Select Column_name, Type, Computed, Length, Prec, Scale, Nullable, TrimTrailingBlanks, FixedLenNullInSource, Collation | Export-Excel -Path ($ResultsPath + $FileName) -WorkSheetname $TableName -Title $TableName -TitleSize "24"-TableName $TableName -TableStyle Medium16 -AutoSize ##Create Page Per Table
```

**

- Original Code:

**

```
## SQL Server Details ##
$SQLServer = 'SERVERNAME'
$Database = 'DATABASE'
$GetTableList = @'
Select name
from sys.tables as T
Where T.name NOT LIKE '[_]%'
'@;
$GetTableInfo = @'
sp_help 
'@

## SQL Connection ##
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True";

$SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$Sqlcmd.CommandText = $TableList
$Sqlcmd.$SQLConnection = $SQLConnection

## Create Data Set ##
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSetTable = $Dataset.Tables["Table"]


## Open Excel and Create Workbook ##
$ExcelDoc = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;
$ExcelDoc.Visible = 0
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelDoc.Workbook.Add()
$ExcelSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.WorkSheets.Item(1)

## Create Table ##

## Table Header ##
[Array] $GetColumnNames = $DataSetTable.Columns | Select ColumnName
[Int] $RowHeader = 1
Foreach ($ColHeader in $GetColumnNames)
{
$ExcelSheet.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader).font.bold = $true;
$ExcelSheet.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader) = $ColHeader.ColumnName;
}

## Adding the rest of the information ##
[Int] $RowData = 2
[Int] $ColData = 1

Foreach ($line in $DataSetTable.Rows)
{
ForEach ($ColName in $GetColumnNames)
{
$ExcelSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
$ExcelSheet.Cells.Item($RowData, $ColName) = $line.$($ColName.ColumnName).ToString()
$ColData++
}
$RowData++; $ColData = 1
}

$ExcelColumnFit = $ExcelSheet.usedRange;
$ExcelColumnFit.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

## Save File ##

$ExcelFile = `
"C:\Temp\DatabaseInformation_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")).xls";

if (Test-Path $ExcelFile)
{
Remove-Item $ExcelFile
$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($ExcelFile);
}
else
{
$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($ExcelFile);
};

## Quit Excel ##
$Excel.Quit(); (Get-Process Excel*) | foreach ($_) { $_.kill() };
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot provide a full example right now but I would recommend looking at two modules that can help you build out the desired Excel file much easier.

- [dbatools](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools)
- [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Both of these modules are available in the PowerShell Gallery so from a machine with Internet access you can simply run the following command to install the latest version:

```
Import-Module dbatools,ImportExcel
```

In dbatools you can utilize `Get-DbaTable` to pull the tables from a given database. This will return the SMO object so you can get access to the `Column` collection on a table to dig into the column names and metadata.

The ImportExcel module provides a more easier method of dumping data you pull from SQL Server into an Excel file. You do not have to use the Office COM Objects which can be just a pain to deal with; you can even use this module without Office installed. The author of the module has published multiple examples that you can go through and see how the module can be utilized [here](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples).

Comment: Thanks! that helped. I've got it working - just adding a few more bits to it now. I've updated with the new script